# react address lookup issue with changing final input value

Tags: reactjs

I am building an address lookup functionality for an app, and my previous 2 questions have thus far, been unable to garner an answer. I am on the last step, and need to figure this out, so I turn to you stack overflow.

I start with an input, a button and a target input:

```
<input type='text' name='postcode-lookup' onChange={this.postcodeChange} />

<button onClick={this.searchPostcode}>Search</button>

<input type='text' name='target-for-data' />
```

Easy enough. Now for the functions attached to both of those elements:

```
postcodeChange = {e} => {
    this.setState({'postcode': e.target.value});
}

searchPostcode = () => {
    this.setState({'visible': true});

    if(this.state.postcode.length . 0){
        Axios.get('postcode look up api here')
        .then(response => {
            this.setState({'response': response.data});
        })
    }
}
```

Ok here, we have 3 state items: postcode, which we will set to an empty string '', visible, which is initially set to true, and response, which is an empty array, that we then populate with the response data of address objects.

My next step, was to display those addresses, so inside the render, I set a const that maps over the response array like so:

```
const result = this.state.response.map((item) => {
    if(this.state.visible === true){
        return(
            <p key={item.id} onClick={addressClick}>{item.address1Field}</p>
        )
    }else {

    }
})
```

Ok, so when we click the button, it will return a `p` tag filled with address data from the array. This also has a function, which is where my problem lies.

Inside of this function I set the visible state item to false, so that the addresses disappear. Easy enough.

But how do I then take the address that I clicked on, and populate it into the original input we started with?

I have tried many things, from setting the state in `addressClick`, targeting the `innerHTML`, `e.target.value`, `e.target.innerHTML`, and so on and so on for hours.

Any takers? Ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood correctly. You want to add the `adress` to the second input's value after the `adress` gets deleted?

Comment: no. when you click the button, it will show say, 6 addresses below it, if thats how many are in the array, one on top of another, as p tags. once you click one of those p tags, the rest dissapear, and the data inside the one you clicked (the address) is populated in the target input.

Answer (score 0):

Not too sure if I fully understand your issue but here is a opens source library which might do what you need out of the box

```
import { AddressAutocomplete } from '@rottitime/react-address-autocomplete'

function App() {
  return <AddressAutocomplete />
}
```

https://github.com/rottitime/react-address-autocomplete

[image: Edit Button]